# ASP.NET connection string for SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, odbc, database-connection, oledb

I am having some trouble with a connection string between an ASP app sat on IIS and an existing SQL Server 2012 instance.

The current connection string that works is as follows:

```
 Data Source=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=CORE;User
 ID=testuser;Password=password;
 MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connection Timeout=200;pooling=false
```

The ODBC driver installed is SQL Server V 6.01.7601.17514. I then added the latest driver SQL Server Native Client 11 and tried adjusting the connection string in IIS with no luck.

I tried both ODBC and OLE DB strings from `connectionstrings.com`.

**OLEDB**

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=SERVER1;Database=CORE;Uid=testuser;Pwd=password;
```

**ODBC**

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=SERVER1;Database=CORE;Uid=testuser;Pwd=password;
```

Each time I get a login prompt which I don't understand why the connection string is failing to supply these details with? What am I missing here?

Just having a look though some of the similar questions, some mentions named pipes which is enabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first connection string is valid for the Net Framework Data Provider (the SqlClient classes), while the others are for the OleDb provider or ODBC provider.

Of course you should use the connection string that your provider understand.

If, in your code, you use the SqlClient classes (SqlConnection, SqlCommand) then you need to use the first connection string, if you use OleDbConnection or ODBCConnection you should use the others

[See connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012)

Comment: So adding this additional SQL Driver makes no difference to the connection?  The reason i wanted to upgrade the driver is i have been told that by upgrading the MDAC it will manage Availability group failover better?  The application currently terminates upon failover which i was hoping to cure using a more up to date driver.

Comment: But if your code works with the NET Framework provider (as I suppose from the working constring) then ODBC driver is not used at all.

Comment: so what i thought i was upgrading the MDAC i was not?

Answer (score 0):

I've always done it this way:

```
Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;UID=;PWD=;
```

I also recommend you put the connection string in a config file for easy editing like this:    http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/store-connection-string-in-web-config